# How to import plain javascript helper classes into React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, helper

I have a React class that I have written in ES6 style such as:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        let HClass = new HelperClass();
    }        
}
```

And my helper class, which exists within the same file, looks like:

```
class HelperClass {
    constructor() {
       this.somevar="";
    }

    some_function= () => {
        //do work
    }
 }
```

However, when trying to construct and run the 'some_function' method, I receive `TypeErrors` stating that the function is not defined.

My questions are:

1. What am I doing wrong to instantiate the HelperClass?
2. Should I be doing something more 'React' like instead of these helper classes? They don't render anything but I need them to manage messages I am processing from ActiveMQ.

Thanks!

Comment: Where did you call `some_function`?

Comment: Nothing in that code is syntactically wrong; however, your `hclass` is only in scope and accessible in the constructor unless you assign it this.

Comment: That was definitely the issue @mattdevio. Thank you!

Comment: Although not syntactically wrong, that isn't how you declare class methods. `some_function () { `.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, `new HelperClass()` is only available inside your constructor. You can use the `some_function` there only.

Generally, you'll do:

For use inside specific method:

```
// outside the constructor
myMethod() {
  let HClass = new HelperClass();
  HClass.some_function();
}
```

For use in any method:

```
// inside the constructor
this.props.HClass = new HelperClass();

// to call
this.props.HClass.some_function();
```

Or, simply using this:

```
// inside the constructor
this.HClass = newHelperClass();

// to call
this.HClass.some_function();
```