# Create React States Using Classes

Tags: reactjs, web, rendering, state

I'm just starting with react. I've seen that most state are comprised of simple data such as object, string, numbers, etc... I was hoping to be able to use a renderless class to hold and control a state like this:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import HumanPlayer from "./players/HumanPlayer";
import Money from "./Money";
import ComputerPlayer from "./players/ComputerPlayer";
import Deck from "./cards/Deck";
import HumanBoard from "./views/PlayerBoard";
import Score from "./views/Score";
import ComputerBoard from "./views/ComputerBoard";
import Controls from "./views/Controls";

class BlackJack extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const human = new HumanPlayer({
      money: new Money({
        currency: Money.USD,
        amount: 100
      })
    });

    super(human);
    const computer = new ComputerPlayer;

    this.state = {
      human: human,
      computer: computer,
      deck: new Deck
    };
  }

  render() {
    const me = this;

    return (
        <div className="BlackJack">
          BlackJack
          <HumanBoard player={me.state.human}/>
          <Score money={me.state.human.getTotal()}/>
          <ComputerBoard player={me.state.computer}/>
          <Controls/>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default BlackJack;
```

Is there a good way to do this or is this more of an anti-pattern?

Comment: What's 'renderless'? Are you referring to container component? The problem with a state consisting of class instances is that it potentially cannot be (de)serialized. This will likely cause architectural problems in future. The question doesn't explain what are these classes and why you need them.

Comment: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52284036/2138752) may help you.

Comment: May I ask for the purpose of `super(human)` in the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

> I was hoping to be able to use a renderless class to hold and control
>   a state

Using a renderless class:

***To hold*** a piece of app's state, that's fine!

***To control*** a piece of app's state, that will properly cause problems with your ReactJS application.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the props to your children as an object which will just send the reference of the object which you can handle easily. Although if two children components are inheriting the same state then you'll need to send primitive values as a prop. Holding a piece of app's state is fine. Rest is upon your requirements.